# image map in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, imagemap

I'm creating a small kids game, where I have a map of ireland in a Panel, and a question will pop up asking the user to click a certain County.
what's the best way of going about dividing the map up into individual sections for each county?

so i'll have a question pop up at random asking "Where is Dublin?" then the use clicks on the black point at dublin.

i have an idea how i'll go about the questions coming up at random(if not i'll be back later), but any suggestions of assigning hotspots to my image?

[image: Map of Ireland]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is one image and it is shown non-rescaled

So you can

1. Pre-calculate and write down in file or data structure locations of
   black dots (i.e. Photoshop)
2. When a user clicks get coordinates
3. Find a nearest black dot to point clicked by user

UPD: With step 1 you can decide some radius of accuracy for each black point. If clicked point is not within radius of accuracy of nearest black point, you can ask user to clarify.

UPD2: One more approach to improve accuracy is to remember color of area for each black point. If color of clicked point is not same of color of area of nearest black point then ask user to click again.

Comment: Step 3 has some issues with it though. If you click in the top corner of the lowest green area, you'll find that the blue area right next to it will have a closer dot than the green area.

Comment: couldn't i shorten the target point down to a simple small box around each point?, the game is mainly for a 6 year old, so i want to make the process as easy as possible

Comment: @Sawyer05, how about combine two approaches UPD and UPD2? It think it should give better accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You could vectorize the map, so that each county is defined as a polygonal shape. There are stock algorithms which determine whether or not a point is inside a polygon. But some of the shapes are pretty complex, so this could be a lot of work.

When you want to keep a rasterized approach, you could put a graphic for each county in a separate image object and have each of them react on clicks. When the user clicks on the panel, you first determine all of these sub-graphics the click is in (they will overlap, so there can be multiple). Then you check if the clicked pixel in each sub-graphic is transparent or not. When it's not transparent, the user clicked on that county.

When you have each county as a separate graphic, there would be a lot of other games you could play with them. Like a jigsaw puzzle or showing the shape and the user has to guess which county it is. I don't know if you would get paid for those, though.

Comment: getting the exact shapes of each county isnt necessarily a priority (although it would be nice), i add the black dots in myself with an idea to simply have a click "box" around each dot, intending the user to have to click the black dot to define each county, just to avoid accidently clicking on other counties.